# How to execute JavaScript in HTML environment

Tags: javascript, html, xss

For a testing project I want to create a [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerable site. My basic structure is a forum where people can add forum posts via input fields and a submit button. Currently I render the new post which should be displayed via innerHTML but with this method the malicious (e.g. `<script>alert("123")</script>`) script which I want to insert as an attacker gets not executed. I searched for other alternatives to innerHTML but none of them worked. How can I achieve JavaScript rendering in my code?

**Things I tried**

```
appendChild();
eval();
insertAdjacentElement();
```

**Input fields for creation new post**

```
<form>
  <label for="topic"
    >Topic:
    <br />
    <input id="topic" required
  /></label>
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="text"
    >Text:
    <br />
    <input id="text" type="text" required
  /></label>
  <br />
  <button type="submit" id="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

**Input example text field** (localStorage is the storage from the input fields)

```
<div id="post">
  <script>
    if (localStorage.length > 0) {
      post.innerHTML += localStorage.key(0);
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Try not using localStorage. It is likely escaping the HTML.

Comment: What do you mean by escaping? @HereticMonkey

Comment: I gues you need a regex that removes dangerous html tags from your input

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

This function gives me actually the desired behaviour.

```
<div id="post">
  <script>
    if (localStorage.length > 0) {
      post.innerHTML += localStorage.key(0);
      eval(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(0)));
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
      <label for="topic"
        >Topic:
        <br />
        <input id="topic" required 
      /></label>
      <br />
      <br />
      <label for="text"
        >Text:
        <br />
        <input id="text" type="text" required 
      /></label>
      <br />
      <button id="submit" onclick="test()">submit</button>
    </form>
        <div id="TESTDIV">
        </div>
        <script>
            function test(){
                if(localStorage.length >0){
                  item+=localStorage.setItem(document.getElementById("topic").value,document.getElementById("text").value); 
                }
       else{
var item=localStorage.setItem(document.getElementById("topic").value,document.getElementById("text").value);
                  }
                  document.getElementById("TESTDIV").innerHTML= localStorage.getItem(document.getElementById("topic").value);
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>



Hi! Hope You are well i think i will works.
```